# Clarify why $\int_\eta^y \frac 1 {x-1} - \frac 1 {x+1} dx = \ln(|1-y|)-\ln(|1+y|)- \ln(|1-\eta|)+\ln(|1+\eta|)$ for $y \in (-1,1)$ and ??

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can someone help me clarify that for $$\int_\eta^y \frac 1 {x-1} - \frac 1 {x+1} dx = \ln(|1-y|)-\ln(|1+y|)- \ln(|1-\eta|)+\ln(|1+\eta|)$$ for $y \in (-1,1)$ and $\eta \in \mathbb R$ ?

What I don't understand here is why $\ln(|x \pm 1|)$ is an anti-derivative ? This function is not differentiable on the interval or is it ?

How does one obtain this anti-derivative ?

Comment: What do you know about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Sorry, how can I use that here ?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus states that the derivative of the integral of a function is the function itself. With it, you need only show that the derivative of $ln|x|$ is $\frac{1}{x},$ and by doing this you're proving the converse as well, hence the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $ln|x|$. After that, it's just a matter of using some change of variables.

Comment: So the absolute value signs come from change of variables ?

Comment: No, the absolute value is due to the fact that without it the equality would hold in $\mathbb{R}^+$ only. To extend it to the whole $\mathbb{R}$ you need to extend the logarithm to the negative x-axis as well, hence the absolute value sign.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are unfamiliar with derivatives of logarithms, namely that 
$\int \frac{1}{x} \ dx = \log(x)$, or equivalently, $\frac{d}{dx} \log(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. (All my log's here are base $e$ and I an omitting constants of integration). So I will try to prove this result to you:

I assume you know about exponentials, for example $\frac{d}{dy} \left(-e^{-y}\right) = e^{-y}.                 (1)$

Now let $y = \log(x)$, so my objective is to prove $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$. Using the chain rule, the LHS of (1) is:

$\frac{d}{dy} \left(-e^{-y}\right) = \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{d}{dx} \left(-e^{-\log(x)}\right) = \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{-1}{x}\right) = \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{1}{x^{2}}$

The RHS of (1) is: $e^{-y} = e^{-\log(x)} = \frac{1}{x}$. Comparing these expressions, we see that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$ QED.

This is equivalent to $\int \frac{1}{x} \ dx = \log(x)$, or by making a substitution $x \mapsto x - a$, $\int \frac{1}{x-a} \ dx = \log(x-a)$ now this is the same form as the integrals in your question so hopefully you understand where the logarithms come from. The only non-continuous ($\Rightarrow$ non-differentiable) real point of $\log(x)$ is at $x = 0$ ($\log(x)$ isn't defined for $x<0$ anyway), hence in your question $y$ is taken to be in the open interval $(-1,1)$ to avoid the discontinuous point $1-1 = 0 = -1 + 1$.

(Important) Remark: Above I have used the fact that $\frac{dy}{dx} \equiv \frac{1}{\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)}$, this is non-trivial and in fact only holds for first order derivatives.

Comment: But why do we have these absolute value signs ?

Comment: This is just a definition of logarithm, it's not defined for negative values. In $\mathbb{R}$ at least.

Comment: Recall the definition of the logarithm: log(y) = x if and only if e^x = y. Note that e^x is always positive (see the graph of e^x), so y can only take positive values. This is why the logarithm is only defined for positive values and it is common to write the absolute value |y|.

Comment: Further, note that (roughly speaking) e^(-infinity) is zero, in other words log(0) = (-infinity), this is where the discontinuous point at 0 comes from.